# Solution of system of three variables

Tags: linear-algebra

On solving 
$$ 2x - 4y + z = 0 $$ 
$$ x + y - 4z = 0 $$ 
$$ x - y - z = 0 $$ 
I get 
$$ y = 0.6 x $$
$$ z = 0.4 x$$
 I thought that there was a rule of thumb that you need as many independent equations as the number of unknowns. So, why don't I get a **unique** solution in this case?

Comment: Your homogeneous system has the trivial solution $x = y = z = 0$. If it was unique, that would be quite boring, wouldn't it? But as @user2345215 explained, it is not unique because your equations are not linearly independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: The matrix of the coefficients of the given system of equations is $$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&-4&1\\1&1&-4\\1&-1&-1\end{pmatrix}$$ with $det(A)=0$ so the equations are not independent. Therefore the fact that you do not get a unique solution is not a  contradiction to what you (correctly) know.

Answer (score 5):

Because
$$\begin{pmatrix}2&-4&1\\1&1&-4\\1&-1&-1\end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}0&-2&3\\0&2&-3\\1&-1&-1\end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&2&-3\\1&-1&-1\end{pmatrix},$$
so the system isn't independent.